# Render PartialView from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

HomeController > Index action does a select query. For each row in that select query, I need to render a Partial View in my Index view. Since this depends on the database, I'm doing this part of the code from the controller. I searched quite a bit, but I can't figure out how to render a PartialView from the controller.

1. Do partial views require a controller action? I wasn't sure about this, but this is what I created:

   ```
   public PartialViewResult ucDropdown(Question question)
   {
       ViewBag.Question = question;
       return PartialView();
   }
   ```
2. In my main view, how do I call this partial view? I have (unsuccessfully) tried:

   ```
   public ActionResult Index(string id = "")
   {
       var q = ......
       var ctrls = new ControlsController();
       ViewBag.Questions = ctrls.ucDropdown(q);
       return View();
   }
   ```
3. How can I access the ViewBag of this partial view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not necessarily need an action method to render a partial view. You can directly call the partial view in your main view and  pass a `Question` object directly.

So in your main view, you can loop through the questions and call the partial view using `Html.Partial` helper method.

```
@foreach(var item in (List<Question>)ViewBag.Questions)
{
  @Html.Partial("ucDropdown",item)
}
```

Assuming you have a partial view called `ucDropdown.cshtml` in either `~/Views/Shared` directory or `~/Views/YourControllerFolderName` and
 `ViewBag.Question` is of type `List<Question>` or `IEnumerable<Question>`

Make sure your partial view `ucDropdown.cshtml` is strongly typed to `Question` type

```
@model Question
<p>@Model.QuestionId</p>
```

Since you are passing the question object directly to view (a strongly typed approach), you do not need ViewBag. You can simply access `Model.AnyPropertyName` in your partial view.